# Links published to my page wall with graph do not show up in user feeds

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a php script that posts links to my facebook page wall using the php sdk that works fantastic except for one minor annoyance. When my links are posted programatically via the api they do not appear in the feeds of people who like the page. When the links are posted manually they show up. My question is: is there any special considerations I need to take into account to make those automatic posts show up or is this just how facebook's algorithm works when choosing content for the feed? I suspect this is more of policy issue than a technical one but facebook has been changing things around so I don't want to jump to conclusions. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I discovered that facebook intentionally penalizes you for auto-posting through the api. Read here: http://sproutsocial.com/insights/2011/04/facebook-penalizes-you-for-automating-your-page-updates/

Bastards. Oh well. Question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version of the API.  Maybe they've resolved a previous bug.